# SSIS email task attachment property

Tags: variables, ssis, email-attachments

the ssis email task has an attachment property. are you able to use an expression or variables as the attachment location? as I want to attach a file that gets generated during the ssis package but it has a date/time stamp in the path so will always be different

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression as the attachment location. Click on the Send Mail Task, then go into expressions on the properties pane. Choose FileAttachments in the property drop down menu, and enter your expression.

[image]

[image]